# "Not to want someone doing something." What shade of meaning is attached to using the gerund rather than infinitive?

Tags: meaning-in-context, gerund-vs-infinitive, cloze-test

On page 137 of *First Certificate Trainer* by Peter May (Cambridge Books for Cambridge Exams), the last paragraph in Test 4, *Use of English Part 2* (a cloze test on a short text entitled *Safe camping*), reads:

> After meals, pick up any bits of food that might be left on the ground, as these can attract insects – or larger creatures. It also makes sense, for the same reason to keep unused food in closed containers well away from the camp. **You don't want a hungry bear or other animal suddenly appearing in your tent!**

Why not the structure "(not) to want someone to do something"? Why not "**You don't want a hungry bear or other animal to suddenly appear in your tent**"? (Or "suddenly to appear in your tent", or "to appear in your tent suddenly"… it is not the place of the adverb I am interested in here.)

The structure "(not) to want someone doing something" is found in the Cambridge Dictionary online, with the example sentence "I don't want a load of traffic going past my house all night, waking me up." But no explanation is given as to when one structure should be used, and when the other.

Comment: You're right; it seems illogical to use a continuous tense. But it's quite idiomatic (ie commonly used and accepted) in this sort of construction. Perhaps it just sounds less po-faced-formal than the equivalent to-infinitive catenation.

Comment: Admittedly it's a small sample size, but Google Books says it has 42 instances of [don't want them turning up](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22don%27t+want+them+turning+up%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) compared to just 7 for [don't want them to turn up](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22don%27t+want+them+to+turn+up%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which accords with my own expectation (and preference). So I'm don't really agree with *"Why not the **more usual** structure?"* above. The actual citation seems far more "normal" than OP's alternative to m e.

Comment: @user58319: I don't think *turning up* is a gerund here. Since a gerund is effectively a noun, that usage would result in *don't want **their** turning up* - just about credible, but unlikely.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: thank you very much for this (to me) new adjective 'po-faced' – perhaps from po 'chamber pot' (19-20 centuries), from French pot, influenced by poker-faced – says my Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English. Anything that sounds dirty must be French, mustn't it?! This rich English of yours is the reason why I keep returning to this site and its bunch of irritating advocates of usage against any kind of rule, any kind of logic. I love-hate you all! To me, it seems logical to use a gerund or a continuous form here!

Comment: @Fumble But with different verbs, the results are quite the opposite. “Don’t want you thinking” yields only 70 results, whereas “don’t want you to think” yields 507,000 (!).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: because you can do your best to reason someone out of thinking something but you cannot reason a bear out of appearing in your tent! Thanks for the editing!

Comment: @Janus: Yes, the exact context is highly relevant. I was specifically focussed on OP's **want + turn up** combination. Which I think would even more markedly favour the **-ing** version with **like** as the first verb, but if we switch to **expect** I expect the opposite would occur.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: because 'turning up' is precisely something you cannot have an influence on since it is unknown to you before you actually see the person or animal arriving.

Comment: @Araucaria: I get 3 results for  "don't want you to leaving" and _they're_ ungrammatical. // Inclusion of 'suddenly' seems to shift the preference away from the to-infinitive construction here, or at least further along the continuum.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite right, thanks! :) That's a typo. Should read "don't want you leaving" compared to "don't want you to leave" Figures are correct for those entries. Agree that "suddenly" might have some effect here too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but try "don't want you leaving" (5,260) versus "don't want you to leave" (151,000). OP is entirely right that ***want*** far more often takes a clause with a so-called *to*-infinitive

Comment: I get 898 000 for "don't want you leaving" on a raw Google search. This is far from insignificant (though I'm sure "don't want you to leave" will have far more hits).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure thing. FumbleFingers' figures  (and mine but not explicitly stated) were for Google *books*. Nearly a million hits is certainly something. I think the question's very interesting.

Comment: @Araucaria, Edwin: The gerund usage was [virtually non-existent a century ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t+want+you+going&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20not%20want%20you%20going%3B%2Cc0), and only really took off in very recent decades, so you have to consider *dates* as well as *totals*. Personally I'd be more likely to use infinitive *"Please stay. I don't want you **to leave me**"*, but gerund *"You can have a Coke now, but I don't want **you leaving your dinner**"*.

Comment: [There's very little difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/198613/15299), and most people don't ever notice when there is.

Answer (score 3):

I commented that I don't think OP's *turning up* was a gerund, but I'm somewhat backtracking on that point now. Whatever - even if it's *not* formally a gerund, it looks quite like one. And there's been a general tendency over the past century or so for [gerunds to replace infinitive forms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=likes%20to%20swim,likes%20swimming&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,likes%20to%20swim;,c0;.t1;,likes%20swimming;,c0).

The main factor controlling the gerund/infinitive choice seems to be the specific verb involved. Thus, looking at a simpler construction...

> *He enjoys swimming* (not *He enjoys to swim*)
>    *He wants to swim* (not *He wants swimming*)
>    *He likes swimming/to swim* (both are okay)

---

There's also this from [englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/part_1.htm), pointing out that *infinitives sound more abstract*...

> Gerunds sound more natural and would be more common in everyday English.
>   Infinitives emphasize the possibility or potential for something and sound more philosophical.
>
> *Learning is important* (normal subject)
>    *To learn is important* (abstract subject - less common)
>    *The most important thing is learning* (normal complement)
>    *The most important thing is to learn* (abstract complement - less common)

To which I would add my own example...

> [*I like you to kiss me*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22like%20you%20to%20kiss%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20like%20you%20to%20kiss%20me%22&tbm=bks)  (sounds dated, formal, starchy to me, and all 6 results are from long ago)
>    [*I like you kissing me*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22like%20you%20to%20kiss%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20like%20you%20kissing%20me%22&tbm=bks) (sounds perfectly natural, but all 58 results are from the past couple of decades)

---

Putting all that together, what it means is native speakers today like ***using gerunds*** wherever possible, whereas a century ago they liked ***to use infinitives***. Actually, I just used those two forms to illustrate my point. Strictly speaking if we go back far enough, native speakers had no choice (because using gerunds like that simply wasn't grammatically possible).

As to whether there's any *semantic* difference, I think the answer is *No, not usually*. But when I consider the following pair...

> [*I hate to eat alone*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22like%20you%20to%20kiss%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20hate%20to%20eat%20alone%22&tbm=bks)
>    [*I hate eating alone*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22like%20you%20to%20kiss%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20hate%20eating%20alone%22&tbm=bks)

...I can easily convince myself it's more likely the first speaker doesn't *actually* eat alone very often. There's more "immediacy" in the gerund/continuous verb form used by the second speaker, which suggests to me he's *currently* eating alone (or at least, frequently does so).

Here's another related context where the *infinitive/gerund* choice definitely makes a difference. I know it's only because of the "when", but still...

> Sports teacher: *"Okay, you kids get changed and go outside while I finish my paperwork - I want you **running/to run** round the track when I come out"*.

---

EDIT: By way of explaining @user58319's assertion that the infinitive *"implies some kind of control or influence"*. This just arises because *in some contexts* the implied *subject* is in fact the speaker...

> *"I don't like **to smoke** in bed"* (so ***I*** don't)
>    *"I don't like **smoking** in bed"* (so please can ***you*** not do it)

Comment: @user58319: I do really think you're stretching a point there! As I hope I've shown above, the biggest factor by far is simply *gerund = modern*. Semantic distinctions are usually minimal (if they exist at all) and probably vary on an almost "case by case" basis. And if I'm forced to distinguish *"He likes to work"* from *"He likes working"*, for example, I would say the infinitive version is better able to carry the sense that *he [sometimes] chooses to work [on personal projects] simply because he likes the activity*. The more familiar gerund just suggests he likes doing his [necessary] job.

Comment: Your "immediacy" is just my idea of "powerlessness" in a different guise! The first speaker does all he can to avoid eating alone, and he is rather successful, whereas the second speaker does not like this situation – eating alone – but is powerless to change it. I agree that infinitives, like simple tenses, are – or have come to be felt to be – 'skeletal' (your 'abstract', 'philosophical') in comparison to gerunds, and continous tenses, which are 'fleshed out', alive… which is only logical since a continous tense shows an action in progress, 'presentifies' it…

Comment: It seems to me you're trying to impose a single semantic distinction that simply doesn't exist. Crucially, the *trend* is to use gerunds more and more. And for any given context, once the gerund is "established", it takes over the "most likely" interpretation. So we look for a "slightly left-field" interpretation if the infinitive is used. But getting "established" is complex. Compare *I like you doing that* (normal), *I like you to do that* (bit weird), *I liked you doing that* (normal), *I liked you to do that* (very weird). Even ***tense*** affects what sounds "normal".

Comment: Clinging to rules I hope will make up for the years I did not spend in an English speaking country imbibing…  modern usage!

Comment: @user58319: I don't want to give the impression I know everything about what's going on here. It's a truly excellent question, and I'm disappointed to see only one other user besides me has upvoted it so far. Particularly when I see completely trivial questions collect several upvotes before being closed. Maybe your question is just too hard for the less insightful users here to even *understand*, but I'm cautiously optimistic that it might turn out to be a "slow burner" from which ***I*** might be able to learn something too (as a final resort, I can easily afford to throw bounties at it! :)

Comment: A major problem is the ill-defined nature of 'gerund', which involves the hopeless synonymy-with-hypernymy. One definition of 'gerund' is 'an -ing form used /functioning as a noun' (aka poss -ing). However, [some people](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/gerund_or_infinitive2.php) use 'gerund' to mean any -ing form. Thus the linked reference gives this as an example of a verb + gerund structure: 'She came running across the field.' I'd class this as the participle instead (in a phase structure); compare the auxiliary construction 'She was running across the field.'

Comment: @Edwin: Your comment has inspired me to think of a context where *running/to run* makes a definite semantic difference, but I'm not sure if it's strictly the usage OP is focussed on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Really did not expect that, considering the negativity my answer raised. I almost deleted it... Thanks for the appreciation.

Comment: @fev: You obviously put quite some thought into your answer, which definitely enhanced my perception of the issues involved here. I don't necessarily think everyone (including myself! :) should have the same opinion about possible nuances of meaning here. But you've given me (and hopefully others, now and on into the future) some interesting food for thought - which I figured was the best I could hope for anyway (so thanks for giving me something to be appreciative of! :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree; the use of the present participle here does seem rather illogical. However much we would like to think that English constructions are well-behaved, we'll quite often be disappointed. It might be instructive to examine the behaviour of other verbs in similar complex catenations here, after an example of a simple catenation:

> He remembered paying.

is obviously (and [famously](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aEnglish_catenative_verbs) – but I would use '-ing form' rather than 'gerund' here; see FF's comment) different in meaning from the catenation with the to-infinitive:

> He remembered to pay.

So we see the participle 'paying' used in a punctive (completed short action) role.

With

> I don't want him turning up.
>
> I don't want him to turn up.

either is acceptable, and there is little change in meaning. This pair come close to OP's examples, but even the inclusion of the adverb 'suddenly' alters 'how it sounds'. 'I don't want him suddenly to turn up' sounds very formal, even starchy; 'I don't want him to suddenly turn up' sounds better but still not as idiomatic as 'I don't want him suddenly turning up'.

With

> I didn't allow him to come.

the to-infinitive is mandatory.

With

> I can't see/imagine *him* coming / turning up [...: he never goes to
>   parties.]

the -ing form is mandatory, even though 'turn up' is punctive.

So, -ing form catenations are not restricted to continuous processes. Even where there otherwise seems a fairly straight choice, with the -ing form perhaps not as appropriate, it may be perversely preferred with some verbs. Choice is probably influenced by the over-formal sound of the to-infinitive alternative.

Comment: You agree… with yourself! Could you comment on your 'little change in meaning'because THIS is the whole point… sounds like 'there is something I know, but I won't tell you, because you wouldn't understand, anyway!' Highly irritating!

Comment: I was agreeing with [the implications of] what you said in your original pre-edit question: Why not the more (usual)[predictable] structure "(not) to want someone to do something"? Why not "You don't want a hungry bear to appear ... The linked Wikipedia article discusses the differences in meaning of certain simple catenations. As far as I know, an equivalent list dealing with complex catenations does not exist. As for **why** certain catenations are permitted, others aren't, and some have counterparts with different meanings, I'd be surprised if the doctorate has yet been written.

Comment: Going on to your "Could you comment on your 'little change in meaning'" I was leaving a little leeway here. Others might claim a nuance suggested by one but not the other in this particular case, but I'd say register swamps that.

Answer (score 1):

This Ngram of "[don't want you *](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t%20want%20you%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdo%20not%20want%20you%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20here%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20getting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20going%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20around%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20or%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20ever%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cdo%20not%20want%20you%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20here%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20getting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20going%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20around%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20or%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdo%20not%20want%20you%20ever%3B%2Cc0)" shows that *to* (I'm sure it's not a preposition) is by far the most productive. So it's unlikely that `not want someone/something to infinitive` is somehow inferior to `not want someone/something V-ing`. If anything, it's the other way around.

I've heard somewhere that Ngram is different from Google Books, but I think the former carries more weight because it's more comprehensive. Having said that, I don't think there's any significant meaning difference between `to-infinitive` and `V-ing` after `not want someone/something`.

There's one thing I can think of, though, about how the `V-ing` can come after `not want someone/something` but not as readily after its positive counterpart `want someone/something` (unless you want to express the progressive aspect as in the example *I want you running round the track when I come out* suggested by @FumbleFingers). And that one thing is the possibility of native speakers parsing `not want` as a single verb such as *dislike*, *mind* or even *resent*. Note that these verbs allow `someone/something V-ing` but not `someone/something to infinitive`:

> *He disliked/minded/resented **his daughter staying** away from home.*
>
> **He disliked/minded/resented **his daughter to stay** away from home.*

This does not mean that they mean "dislike/mind/resent etc." by saying `not want`. It's just that they could be treating `not want` as a single verb without changing its meaning. So there's no significant difference in meaning.

As long as they don't parse `not want` as a single verb, they still can freely use `to infinitive`. Therefore, the two structures can co-exist.

Answer (score 0):

… and here is why:

'(not) to want someone to do something' implies some kind of control or influence over  what the speaker tries to encourage someone to do or discourage them from doing, some kind of power over them.

In the case of the bear, obviously, you just do not want the thing to happen but you know perfectly well you do not have any influence on it happening or not! Apart from taking precautions such as not keeping any food in or near the tent…

And it is more often the case with things we do **not** want to happen than with things we do want to happen; the negative can carry the idea or powerlessness, which would explain why 'not to want someone doing something' can be found together with 'not to want someone to do sth'!

There is a reason behind usage!

Comment: I disagree with the statement that “‘(not) to want someone to do something’ implies some kind of control or influence”. Whether you use the infinitive or the participle, control or influence is _entirely_ dependent on the context, not the grammatical structure. “I don’t want you to die!” is perfectly common, even though obviously we have no control or influence whatsoever over whether someone else will die or not.

Comment: I see absolutely _no_ such distinction. None at all. Imagine, for example, a parachute instructor saying, “I’ll come round and double-check that you all have everything set up properly and safely. We don’t want you getting hurt on your very first jump!”. Are you seriously saying that would be a case of expressing a feeling a kind of powerlessness over the situation, while if he had said “we don’t want you to get hurt”, he would feel in control? That is quite obviously **not** the case. He’s doing what he can to influence the situation in either case.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: 'I don't want you to die!' means 'I will do all I can for you not to die!'… and I want you to believe in my power to do so. 'I don't want you dying!' would sound fatalistic, I do not want this to happen but there is nothing I can do to prevent it… a very weak way of supporting anyone about to die!  –

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: 'you might get hurt, but we will do all we can to reduce that risk' (gerund) versus 'you won't die, don't even think about it!' (infinitive)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: avoiding liabilities… We never said you would not get hurt!

Comment: More like jocular, light-hearted (participle) vs. serious, admonishing (infinitive). That’s the only difference I can force out of the different forms (and it’s only a tendency, not hard-and-fast). Nothing else than that. You’re trying to force a preconceived notion on to actual usage data that clearly contradicts the preconceived notion.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: you must be jo… cularising! I know you are not. I know you are right, but English (to a foreigner) is a labyrinth – a thing of a-maze-ment – and when at a crossroads or a junction, you have to have some kind of rule or reasoning to help you choose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14832/discussion-between-user58319-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Comment: I understand your point, and I agree there must be *something* governing the *to verb/verbing* choice in such constructions. I must be using some principle to predict reasonably accurately which pairs of verbs are more likely to favour **-ing**, before finding confirmation on Google Books. So far I'm not consciously aware what that "something" is, but I don't *think* it's a matter of whether you (or whoever the subject is) has any control over the activity.

Comment: 'I/We don't want you dying' is in a less formal, less sombre, more tongue-in-cheek register. You wouldn't use that register with someone who was near death's door.

Answer (score 0):

We are discussing the catenative verb ***don't want*** in a complex construction with a gerund-participial. The subject of the catenative verb is ***you*** and its object is the non-finite clause *a hungry bear or other animal suddenly appearing in your tent*, where the NP ***a hungry bear or other animal*** is the agent of the verb in gerund ***appearing.*** "Want" in the affirmative is [generally](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-to-infinitive-and-the-ing-form) said to be followed by a "to infinitive" (except for the concealed passives of the *kitchen wants painting* type). Even in the negative, if the subject of "want" is the same as the agent of the verb of the object clause, the to infinitive will be used ("I don't want to leave"). So it is good to narrow the issue you are raising to the particular instance of ***non-affirmative catenative "want" followed by an object clause where the agent of the verb is different from the subject of "want"***.

In theory, the difference in meaning between *I don't want you **doing*** and *I don't want you **to do*** is negligible. I found a short reference to the use of gerund-participials after ***want*** and ***don't want*** in Rodney Huddleston & Geoffrey K. Pullum (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, pp. 1231-1232):

> The gerund-participial with *want* generally has **a progressive
> interpretation**, but *in non-affirmative contexts it can be
> non-progressive*.
>
> - *I want them standing* when the Minister enters
>
> is equivalent to
>
> - *I want them to **be** standing* when the Minister enters,
>
> contrasting with non-progressive
>
> - *I want them to stand* when the Minister enters.
>
> However, in
>
> - ***I don't want you bringing*** your dog with you,
>
> the meaning is ***to bring***, ***not to be bringing***.

However, almost 20 years passed since that grammar was published and anyway it was only concerned with the *progressive* or *non-progressive* nuance of the meaning. Gerunds have seen an increase in use, and although it is difficult to find more exhaustive explanations on this issue, I think people in their conscience may have begun to give it a slight nuance. In your context, it looks like the author of the statement explains ***generally*** a situation in which this ***sudden turning up*** of the bear might happen ***every time*** the situation is repeated. So

> You don't want a hungry bear or other animal *suddenly appearing* in your tent [***every time*** you leave bits of food on the ground or keep unused food in open containers in the camp].

The author may have felt that

> You don't want a hungry bear or other animal *to suddenly appear* in your tent.

is more punctual, for one particular situation, rather than for repeated instances of the same circumstances.

In support of that, I found this post of a native English speaker:

> Go for the gerund, if you want to stress *repeated action*: "*I don't want you **coming** home so late*". *I don't want you **to come** home so late*,(using the infinitive), is more likely to infer the action happening once, or occasionally, of course depending on the context. ([WordRef](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dont-want-you-coming-to-come-home-gerund-participle-infinitive.2178859/post-10910780))

Here is another [thread](https://www.englishforums.com/English/SomeoneSomeone/qdvlr/post.htm) that agrees with the two nuances:

> There's usually no difference intended in sentences like this, but here are a few comments on nuances. *"I didn't want anyone *thinking* I was trying to be a pet of the teacher"* sounds a bit like the 'anyone' might be thinking this for a long time. I didn't want that. *"I didn't want anyone to think I was trying to be a pet of the teacher"* sounds a bit like maybe the 'anyone' might just think this briefly.

Another [post](https://www.quora.com/I-dont-want-you-to-do-or-I-dont-want-you-doing-which-one-is-correct) from an MA Linguistics says:

> The nuance is slightly different.
>
> “I don’t want you to do that” has the slight implication that you
> haven’t done it before. Mother says to child, “I brought some chips
> home, but I don’t want you to eat them.”
>
> “I don’t want you doing that” implies that you were caught in the act
> of doing it, or have been in the habit of doing it. Mother says to
> child, “That’s the third time all the chips have disappeared! I don’t
> want you eating those chips!”
>
> But it’s just a slight nuance. Really, either form could be used in
> either case.

This last post adds another slightly different nuance, that of ***habit***, but the emphasis on repetitiveness conveyed by the gerund-participial and non-repetitiveness conveyed by the to infinitive is obvious. It could point to the ***habit*** that bears have of coming near humans when they smell food.

Comment: Fine detective work.

Comment: I don't understand how you could argue the OP's context supports a repeated action. Even if it's a repeated action by way of being a "habit", you cannot explain why the affirmative _want_ doesn't allow V-ing for the same repeated action.

Comment: @JK2 The OP did not ask to explain why the affirmative of "want" does not license V-ing. And the fact that it does not license it is very well documented.

Comment: No, OP didn't. Regardless, I was just pointing that out to show that the "very well documented" behavior of the affirmative _want_ does not support your logic.

Comment: Also, it's a very bold argument that the verb usage could change so dramatically within just two decades that CaGEL cannot be trusted. Actually, it's not even two decades. Two other posts you've cited are written in 2011, which is less than a decade from CaGEL's publication. So you're essentially arguing that the verb usage has changed in several years. Good luck with that. More importantly, even if that were all true, it's hard to believe that people would be making that kind of subtle distinction when speaking/writing these constructions.

Comment: @JK2 I did state in the beginning that _it is good to narrow the issue you are raising to the particular instance of non-affirmative catenative "want" followed by an object clause where the agent of the verb is different from the subject of "want"._ So I am speaking about the non-affirmative form of "want", not of its affirmative. Language is like that, if one nuance is possible in the negative, it doesn not mean it will be the same in the affirmative.

Comment: @JK2 I am sorry, but I did not say that  CaGEL cannot be trusted. I only said that maybe people are starting to _**add**_ nuances that were maybe not present or recorded at that time.

Comment: Finally, the Ngram in my answer suggests that the "to infinitive" usage has exponentially increased since around 2000 whereas the "V-ing" usage has also increased during the same period but definitely not as dramatically. So honestly, I don't know what you mean by "gerunds have seen an increase in use".

Comment: @JK2 The reverse appears to be true.  Hard to see from the plot, but "to infinitive" about tripled since 2000 and "getting" and "going" did even better than that.

Comment: @cruthers I think you're right. "V-ing" did do better than "to infinitive" in terms of the rate at which their usage increased over the last two decades. Still, I don't believe that the difference in the rate of their usage increase is enough to support the outlandish claim that somehow the usage has so dramatically changed that the usage description of the 2002 grammar by H&P should be revised.

Answer (score -2):

I would simplify this by adding both would be possible in this particular situation.

However the use of 'appearing' puts you into the perspective of it happening at that moment of hearing the phrase spoken, rather than being a future idea. It makes it feel more present, thus more possible to the listener.