# What's the difference between "afraid of + verb" and "afraid to + verb"?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between "afraid of + verb" and "afraid to + verb"?

Isn't "afraid of" used more for generalisations and "afraid to"
for a particular situation? For example:

She's afraid of touching spiders.

She's afraid to touch the spider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some verbs, there is certainly a distinct difference.

> She is afraid of taking the path that leads through the
>   crocodile-infested swamp

would usually be taken as meaning 'She is very worried that she might accidentally choose the dangerous route'.

> She is afraid to take the path that leads through the
>   crocodile-infested swamp

means 'She doesn't want to venture that way'.

**Afraid to V** means anxious, perhaps cripplingly so, about a certain choice. So you wouldn't say 'I'm afraid to slip on a banana skin.'

**Afraid of Ving** might mean the same, but means 'afraid that N might happen by chance' if that reading is possible. 'Afraid of slipping' means 'afraid that a slip might well occur'. But 'afraid of flying' doesn't have the 'happen by chance' reading available.

Answer (score 8):

As [McCawley 1998](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html) puts it (p.126)

> Roughly speaking,
> • *that*-complements [tensed clauses] correspond to **propositions**
> • *for-to* complements [infinitives] correspond to **situation types**
> • *'s-ing* complements [gerunds] correspond to **events**

*Afraid* is a psych predicate adjective (formed from the same root as *fear* and *fright*) that takes the experiencer
of an emotion as its subject, and a prepositional phrase denoting the source of the fear.

The prepositional phrase must have a noun phrase as its object.

- *She's afraid of spiders/that dog/the dark/her shadow.*

Gerunds (but not infinitives) may appear as noun phrase objects of prepositions.

- *He's afraid of spilling the beans/running a marathon/loving too much/sleeping through it.*
- **He's afraid of (to) spill the beans.*

*Afraid*, however, **can** also take a direct infinitive complement, but without a preposition.

- *He's afraid to spill the beans/run a marathon/love too much/sleep through it.*

The difference between the gerund and the infinitive constructions with *afraid*
(and most similar predicates) -- to the extent there is any, which isn't much -- is that, using McCawley's "rough" terminology, the infinitive may refer to fear by the subject of the results of the action (a situation type), while the gerund can refer to a fear that the subject may perform the action anyway (an event).

- *He's afraid of touching cats, so he wears gloves when they're around.*
- *He's afraid to touch cats, because he thinks they make you crazy.*

But most likely this kind of distinction amounts to very, **very** fine-scale tuning for most English speakers, and in the right contexts, infinitive and gerund could be turned around with no ill effects.

Answer (score 4):

There is little difference between the two.
The form is: "afraid ***of*** + ***noun/gerund***" and "afraid ***to*** + ***verb***".

Also, there is no such generalisation. You may use either of them as per your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the meaning of the two sentences has nothing to do with any distinction in the phrases *afraid of* and *afraid to* themselves.  Instead, the difference results from using the generic noun *spiders* in the first sentence and using the definite article *the*  *(spider)* in the second.

So, both "*She's afraid of touching spiders*" and "*She's afraid to touch spiders*" are generalisations about her fear of spiders. And both "*She's afraid of touching the spider*" and "*She's afraid to touch the spider*" refer to her fear of touching a particular spider.

Comment: But you can also say "she's afraid of touching a spider". The difference **is** about the prepositions.

Comment: @curiousdanii. You are right; you can also say "she's afraid of touching *a spider*". But my answer addresses the semantic difference in the OP's two example sentences - which results from article use. Other answerers have focused solely on the question title.

Answer (score 0):

"AFRAID OF"

This is use before a noun or an object, pronoun (her me him us them it)

"AFRAID TO"

This is use before a verb in its base form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please consider providing links to sources to support your answers, [for great sources see this post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)