# 'd hate to be vs. 'd hate being

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, conditionals, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which of the following two structures is grammatically correct? Why?

1. I'**d hate to be** questioned by the FBI.
2. I'**d hate being** questioned by the FBI.

Comment: The answer to the following question seems relevant, as it mentions "hate" (though not in a conditional context): [Not to want someone doing something. What shade of meaning is attached to this structure? (gerund rather than infinitive)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174266/n/174286#174286). If you want to learn more about the grammar of phrases like this, you may also want to look in general at the answers to other questions with the tag [infinitive vs. gerund](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitive-vs-gerund).

Comment: @sumelic: Thanks for your editing and reference to the tag.

Answer (score 2):

"I'd hate to be questioned.." suggests not wanting to be in a situation which requires questioning by the FBI. "I'd hate being questioned..." suggests a fear of the actual questioning process.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While the first one would probably be more typical, both are possible. To my ear, the difference is:

1. I'd hate to be in a situation that that would warrant questioning by the FBI.
2. I'd hate to be in a room with FBI agents questioning me.

The first example could also mean the same as the second, but the second could only mean that you would hate the process. The difference is only evident when in relation to each other.

Using the to-infinitive makes it more abstract, while the present participle makes it more dynamic and therefore more immediate (evoking images of intensity, grilling, discomfort,perspiration).

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm really confused about using the gerund after "would hate". A friend of mine told me that using the gerund here is incorrect.

Comment: Unusual, but not entirely incorrect. Most times the infinitive would be a safe option.